# does renaming column values in an issues log mess up the current values?

Tags: 2010

I have a issues log in Sharepoint 2010 and have been asked if the "priority "column values are changed from the original values (currently they are named “Low”, “Medium”, “High”) to new values, will the current values remain the same, so that a set of 6 values will exist instead of only 3?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the three choices with three other choices, the values in existing list items will stay as they are. As soon as an existing list item is edited, the field control will pull the current choices into the drop-down and will display the first option from the drop-down in the field.

So, until each of the existing items are edited, the old values will still show in views and in the read-only form.